# how to use/integrate "Uploadify" in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, forms, javascript

I want to use uploadify to add the images in my custom form.
I have placed all the `js` and `css` to their respective places but what I didn't understand is how to use the jquery functions in the form as it is used in the uploadify form.

here is the `index.php` of uploadify which has its form.

```
<h1>Uploadify Demo</h1> 
    <form>
        <div id="queue"></div>
        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*')">Upload Files</a>     
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php $timestamp = time();?>
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5("unique_salt" . $timestamp);?>'
                },
                'method'   : 'post',
                'swf'      : 'clas/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : 'clas/uploadify.php'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I know we can use the jquery function like this in the `phtml` files in frontend, but how I can use this in backend.
here is my custom form for the image

```
  <?php
  class Vertax_Blog_Block_Adminhtml_Article_Edit_Tab_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
  {
 protected function _prepareForm()
 {
     $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
     $this->setForm($form);
     $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('image_form',
                     array('legend'=>'image'));      
      $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
      'label'     => 'Image',
      'required'  =>  false,
      'name'      => 'image',
      'multiple'  => 'multiple',
      'mulitple'  =>  true,
      ));         
      if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBlogPostData()) {
      $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBlogPostData());
      Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBlogPostData(null);
      } elseif (Mage::registry('article_data')) {
      $form->setValues(Mage::registry('article_data')->getData());
      }
      return parent::_prepareForm();
   }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @DavidManners I tried but didn't able to do it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about JS and uploadify